# Gwt application font incompatibility issues in FireFox compare to IE

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using Gwt 2.2.0 and Gxt 2.2.3, when i am running the application in Fire-Fox the font styles are bit different compare to IE7. If i am not wrong have seen the same incompatibility issues in the [Gxt Gwt Demo](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#advancedcombobox) site also. Is it a Gxt issue or is there any possibility that we can overcome this issue. Please find below for the screen shots.
Here we can easily observe the differences in font. The label which is displayed on top of the 'Headings' panel is rendered differently in different browsers.I have applied the following style to this label:

```
font-family: Verdana, Sans-serif;
font-size: .8em;
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
```

When i debug and check the styles in IE and FF both are same. But they are rendering differently.

***In IE:***

[image]

***In FireFox:***

[image]

Comment: how they can be a *bit* different? Isn't the same font? Please provide enough information by editing your question.

Comment: IE has different default kerning, what's the problem?

Comment: @EliranMalka: how to make those two fonts similar. I there a way to do that? or is it an gxt issue?

Comment: why is this such an issue? does it break anything? user agents differ in implementation (here the kerning and / or aliasing varies a little), and some quirks just not worth the hassle of "fixing" them. i wouldn't bother with it.

Comment: @EliranMalka - I have updated the screen shots with style where the rendering was not proper .

Comment: try assign a fixed value to the `font-size` (e.g. `px`) and see if it helps.

Comment: @EliranMalka - I have set the 'font-size' explicitly in 'PX' still no use

Answer (score 0):

> If i am not wrong have seen the same incompatibility issues in the Gxt Gwt Demo site also.

I have no IE7, but I see no differences between FF and IE8 set in IE7 compatibility mode.

In regard to your issue, usually this can be explained by different default font sizes and styles set for the `<body>` or for the parent element (or parent-parent-... element) in the browsers.

In simple words, .8em - equals to "default font size" multiply 0.8.

Try to reset the default font size and style explicitly for `<body>`, or `<table>`, or whatever you use as a basic container.

Quick googling gives an explanation:
http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_units.html

> Ems are a relative measurement unit. One 'Em'(1em) is equal to the
>   height of the capital letter "M" in the default font size. When
>   applied in CSS, the Em represents either the user's default font size,
>   or the size of the parent element's font size, if one is available.
>   When using Ems for sizing fonts, the fonts will resize according to
>   the browser's default font size setting.